# File name too long @ rb_sysopen - /app/.env. - Read aws secret manager variable - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ecs, dotenv, aws-secrets-manager

I'm hosting my ruby on rails app on AWS ECS.

For the environment variables, I'm using AWS secrets manager.

The problem is that, when i try to retrieve ENV["RAILS_ENV"], i do not retrieve "production" if I'm in production but a hash map with all the secret variables from aws secrets manager (eg {"RAILS_ENV": "production", "JWT_SECRET":"xxx", ...}.

That triggers the following error when the app is launched.

```
File name too long @ rb_sysopen - /app/.env.
{
    "RAILS_ENV": "production", 
    "JWT_SECRET":"xxx", 
    ...
}
.local (Errno::ENAMETOOLONG)
```

Which is quite problematic.

It happens because one of the env var is used to access a file in the configuration (that's what i guess, i'm not sure)

Anyone has an idea why the env var are coming all together and not separetaly ?

--SOLUTION--

Here is how i solved it.

I try to split the env hash map into all env variables before it was used somewhere

(I tried in config > application.rb but it was not good)

The place where it was fixing the bug was in config > boot.rb

just before that line :

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)
```

I added that code :

```
require 'aws-sdk-secretsmanager'
if(ENV['RAILS_ENV'] && ENV['RAILS_ENV']!="development")
    secret_hash = JSON.parse(ENV['RAILS_ENV'])
    ENV['JWT_SECRET'] = secret_hash['JWT_SECRET']
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = secret_hash['RAILS_ENV']
    ....
end
```

And that fixed the problem

If you have better solution, feel free to share them

I tried to fetch the env variables from aws secret manager.